# Getting a reference to a parent class instance from within an injected object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im wondering if there is any way to pass a reference down to an injected object in Javascript. Cannot use inheritance in this case as this class will take many objects as parameters within its constructor that are created elsewhere.

```
class Parent {

    private Child child;

    constructor(child: Child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    // method needs to be called from within the `child`
    public log(message: string) {
        // logs out "Parent logged: This is a log message from the child"
        console.log(`Parent logged: ${message}`);
    }
}
```

```
class Child {

    private Parent: parent;

    constructor() { }

    log() {
        parent.log("This is a log message from the child");
    }

}
```

If the object is built in the `Parent` constructor, you can just pass a reference in and then assign it to a property within `Child`. However, unfortunately the object is created outside the `Parent` class.

```
    this.child = new Child(this);
```

Comment: Why not extend the Parent instead? https://tsplay.dev/mArqkW

Comment: Can't for this case, as the `Parent` will take many objects as parameters. Its a 'builder' class that takes 5 injected objects. Each one needs access to the logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a setter method on the child that allows you to set the parent, right?

```
class Child {
    private Parent: parent;

    constructor() { }

    setParent(parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
    }

    log() {
        this.parent.log("This is a log message from the child");
    }
}
```

---

Editing here, since I can't put code in the comment well. This is a much more complex example, but it's a well-defined pattern.

A similar example is the `Datasource` class in Apollo GraphQL, which has a base class that all of your "children" would implement, and you use that for cross-dependency with anything:

```
interface SomeDataSources {
  someChild1: SomeChild1;
  someChild2: SomeChild2;
  someChild3: SomeChild3;
}

interface SomeContext {
  datasources: SomeDataSources;
  logger: Logger;
  dbConnection: Connection;
}

class BaseDataSource {
  context: SomeContext;
  initialize({ context }: { context: SomeContext }) {
    this.context = context;
  }
}

class EachChildDoesThis extends BaseDataSource {
  ...
}

/**
 * Instead of using a `Parent` class, this method does all of the
 * dependency injection and closures necessary.
 */
const buildContext = async ({ logger, dbConnection }): Promise<SomeContext> => {
  const context: SomeContext = {
    logger,
    dbConnection,
    dataSources: {
      someChild1: new SomeChild1(),
      someChild2: new SomeChild2(),
      someChild3: new SomeChild3(),
    }
  }

  for (const dataSource of Object.values(context.dataSources)) {
    await dataSource.initialize({
      context,
    });
  }
  
  return context;
};
```

Now you have an entire suite of functionality here that all have access both to the things you're passing in and to each other (dependency-injectedly) by doing this:

```
const logger = new Logger();
const dbConnection = createConnection(dbConfig);

const context = buildContext({ logger, dbConnection });
```

Any one of those child classes could do something like:

```
class SomeChild1 extends BaseDatasource {
  async someMethod() {
    this.context.logger.info('something something');
    // or use the db
    await this.context.dbConnection.doSomething();
    // or even access its siblings
    await this.context.dataSources.someChild2.delete('some-user-id');
  }
}
```

Because of the dependency injection, each one of these is fully stand-alone, testable, and composable.

Comment: Yeah... I considered it. I think I need to re-architecture the code to get a setter to work. There's an issue with the dependency graph that's making a simple setter difficult to fit. I'll take a look :)

Comment: @Kris I've updated this to include the DataSources pattern. It's much more complex, but it's highly composable and testable. Hope it's not unwelcome, and I hope it's helpful for you

Comment: Thank you! I'll read it!

Comment: This is really nice. The one thing I noticed is that when children use the context Typescript thinks it can be undefined. But thats okay. `this.context?.something()`

Comment: I suppose you can also get circular dependencies as well but thats cool (if say, `child1` is part of the context and is passed down to `child1`)

Answer (score 0):

You could the following:

```
class Parent {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  child = {};
  
  constructor(name: string, age: number, child: Child) {
    this.child = child;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  static countParents() {
    return `Parent count at: 10.`;
  }

  log(message: string) {
    console.log(`Parent logged: ${message}.`);
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  favoriteHero: string
  message: string

  constructor(name, age, favoriteHero) {
    super(name, age, favoriteHero);
    this.favoriteHero = favoriteHero;
  }

  bio() {
    return `${this.name} is 12 and his favorite super hero is ${this.favoriteHero}!`
  }
}

const charlie = new Child('Charlie', 12, 'Batman')

charlie.log('Good things') // Parent logged: Good things. 
console.log(charlie.bio()); // Charlie is 12 and his favorite super 
  hero is Batman!
console.log(Parent.countParents()); // Parent count at: 10
```